# Is there a way to change the text of an Action Bar Menu Item when I touch the menu item in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-menu

When I touch this "Edit" button I want it to change to "Done". Is there a way to do this?

[image]

I tried this but it only works when opening the menu on the right side:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // change the text here.

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, at some point, you inflate the menu, yes?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.some_menu_layout, menu);
    return true;
}
```

So you can go into your menu (in this case, `res/menu/some_menu_layout.xml`), and find the `android:id` of the menu item you want to find. You should then be able to use `menu.findItem(theId).setTitle("Done");`. (You may have to save your `Menu` variable as a local member to do this.)